# PHPExcel getRowIterator() and sequence of rows

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
// include PHPExcel library here
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5(); 
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( "file.xls" );


// get excel file rows as array
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
```

Question is: `$rowIterator` array    always have same  sequence of elements (rows), as they are in excel file? it is guaranteed?

Comment: it should be? What's happening?

Comment: @delboy1978uk - What do you mean when you asking "it should be?"  There is not  necessary to have php array and excel same sequence of rows ?

Comment: do you have code question? whats your expected versus actual output?

Comment: @delboy1978uk - For example, if there is 3 rows in excel file, with values: `111`, `222`, `333`, there is possible that output array will like this: `array("222","333","111")` ?  or array always will be: `array("111","222","333")`